# How do I make a bin unique without taking it as key in Aerospike?

Tags: database, bin, aerospike, java-client

I want to store two records in a set only when those records have different values in a specified bin. For example, in a set containing 3 bins of `(CS, P, Fees)`, I tried to store 3 different records:

```
Record1(CS1, P1, Fees1)
Record2(CS2, P1, Fees2)
Record3(CS3, P2, Fees2)
```

Only `Record1` and `Record3` are allowed and `Record2` is not allowed.

How can I make a bin unique in Aerospike?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not allowed'? Aerospike is a KV system, and your record operations are completely independent of the data in other records. No coordination or lookup between them at all. If they have a unique 3-tuple of (namespace, set, PK) there is no connection between them at all.

Answer (score 0):

**As far as I know, you can't achieve that by aerospike (at least by community edition).**
What you are looking for is what we call 'unique index', which make sure that the indexed field not store duplicate value.
'unique index' is not supported by [aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/indexes), or [rethinkdb](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/python/).

If you want to know more (please don't mark this as irrelevant, just a hint for the author) :
You can try [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) to use unique index. However, pay more attentions, you have to do the tradeoff and give up the advantages which aerospike can provide.